# Visual Studio + Chrome = 100% CPU

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010, google-chrome, iis-express

I'm developing an application - something I've done on the same machine for the last x years.

I'm still using XP on this machine - VS 2010. I've also recently changed from the default dev host to IIS 7.5.

At them moment, I'm checking out Google Polymer - this is where the root of my problem lies. When I click on a trivial link to open a dropdown menu, the CPU goes into overdrive and stays there. This only happens on Chrome, not Firefox.

I eliminated a rogue polymer installation by linking direct to the polymer site url's.

I paired the page down so its just html - no aspx.

I put the page up on codepen and I do not get the same issue.

I removed all extensions from Chrome and reset my settings.

I switched betwen IIS and the default dev host.

After these tests, the only variant is that copepen runs the page and I run the page. Therefore my conclusion is that it must be something to do with VS or IIS/dev host.

I'm scratching my head as to where to go next with this. Has anyone else had similar experiences when testing on Chrome?

Help!

Comment: Hey woz - want reporting :) - you could at least have followed up with something useful/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After liasing with the guys from polymer project for sometime, I decided that polymer wasn't ready for production just yet.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed here : VS 2013 (32bit) + Google Chrome = 100% CPU Windows 8 & 10

You need to diable BrowserLink option in the VS 2013
here is how you can disable it
http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link#disabling